# The System cannot find the file specified error while deleting folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi can some one suggest me how to delete below folder(abc) using a batch file?

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc
```

I tried like `RD %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc /Q /S`

But it is not deleting and when I execute the same command in command line it is giving a message like "The System cannot find the file specified" even though it is exists.

Any solution?

Comment: The Git Bash works so perfectly for this problem. Why dont Microsoft just integrate bash as part of the Windows system already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a command line run:

```
ECHO %UserProfile%
```

What does it return?

Open that directory in Windows Explorer and double check that a folder called `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc` exists in it.

I'm thinking that maybe it doesn't exist, and the folder you're looking at that you said does exist, is in a directory with a root that is different from `%UserProfile%`.

### Update

Open a new command window by doing the following, which ensures that it's in Administrator mode.

On a Shortcut to a command window, Right Click > Properties > Shortcut > Advanced and check the "Run As Administrator" checkbox, and click OK twice. Then run the command prompt via the shortcut. You'll know it worked if it looks like this, with the word "Administrator" in the title, see screenshot below. Then try running your RD command again.

[image]

Comment: When I try to run "CD %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc" in the command prompt it is going to that folder without any issue. whereas RD is only not working. Is it because of permissions?

Comment: Yes, my guess is that it's a permissions issue. What happens if you try to delete the folder from Windows Explorer? (Closing the command prompt window first :) )

Comment: Yes it is deleting when I open that from windows

Comment: Open a new command window by doing the following, which ensures that it's in Administrator mode . On a Shortcut to a command window , Right Click > Properties > Shortcut > Advanced and check the "Run As Administrator" checkbox, and click OK twice. Then run the command prompt via the shortcut, and try the RD command again.

Comment: Updated answer with instructions and screenshot.

Comment: But I want to execute this command in end user machine where I cant expect admin privilege. :(

Comment: I think that these security measures from Windows are actually intended to not allow you to do that.

Answer (score 26):

Use 7-zip to "move" them.

When facing an inability to delete a file because of "the system cannot find the file specified" I've tried all the common tricks (verify permissions, command line, free unlocker tools, etc).
What finally got rid of them for me was 7-zip. Using 9.20 "7-zip File Manager" interface (not just the right click on file options) I was able to "Move" the folder which contained the problem files.  Sure, that just moves the problem but there is the beauty, you move them to a disk you can format: a VMDK, a thumb drive, etc... problem solved ;)

Comment: awesome solution

Comment: This worked for me after a lot of looking for solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You have one better. Use 7-zip interface to navigate to the folder and then click delete. For some reason the file manager in 7-zip works much better than windows in different cases where file explorer or cmd fails you

Comment: I had a file ending in a dot (without extension) that Win 10 file manager could not rename/delete. With the 7-Zip file manager I could rename it without problems.

Comment: Windows 11, and a folder I had created through code from "user input" using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Test / Folder"). The folder contains a forward slash. This clearly confused Windows (it created the folder "Test " with subfolder "Folder"). I tried a number of things (https://www.infopackets.com/news/10050/how-fix-cant-delete-file-folder-system-cannot-find-file-specified) and eventually saw mention of using WinRAR elsewhere, so I decided to use the already installed 7-Zip interface with the "Delete files after compression" option selected. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you!  This also works for me, even from the Windows 10 Installation/Repair command line (Shift+F10 upon initial install screen).  I used `7zFM.exe` because GUI is just easier :) Excellent solution, +1.

Answer (score 26):

I used "rm -rf PATH_TO_FOLDER" command line on Git Bash (not cmd), then I can delete the similar folder.
Note: Tested on Windows 10 (latest version).

Comment: Worked Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by one of the answers, but instead of using 7-zip I used WinRAR to archive the empty folder. Before archiving the folder there is an option to delete the folder after archiving, select that option and once the folder is a zip file, the folder should be deleted, and you can go ahead and delete the zip file. I am not sure if it will work for you but it worked for me after spending hours on the internet trying to find a solution.

Comment: Worked for me too. Not sure why this works but thank you.

Comment: I tried eveything cmd, all things and nothing was working. Then you came like an angel and solved it in a click. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me.

1. Open command prompt
2. Browse to parent directory of the folder you want to delete
3. run 'dir /x' (displays short names - xxxxxx~1)
4. run 'rd xxxxxx~1' substituting the folder name you want to delete.

I had a problem where two Pictures folders would show under my user profile, and windows wouldn't let me delete the second folder.

Answer (score 7):

The only solution that worked for me was to put \\?\ in front of the path when running `rd` in command prompt.

For example, to delete **D:\bad\folder**

Open CMD and then type:

```
rd /s "\\?\D:\bad\folder"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the directory name in quotes:

```
rmdir /q /s "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc"
```

Otherwise the spaces in the directory name will be interpreted as argument separators.